# Ensuring a minimum version with use-package

Tags: package, use-package, version-support

In my `.emacs`, I would like to ensure that the `s` package, version 1.10.0 or newer, is installed. If I use `(use-package s :ensure t)` it will not upgrade the installation on systems with older versions of `s`. How do I ensure that the minimum version is present?

Comment: I do not think that use-package supports this.  It's rather unusual to have minimum version bounds in a personal configuration, because most people update regularly anyway.  And with MELPA version bounds don't really work anyway.

Comment: I looked in the `use-package` source and there doesn't seem to be an obvious way to do it with `use-package`. Is there another way to do it?

Comment: Well, sure, there's always the package.el API which you can use to update a package programmatically.  That's not a nice API though so consider whether it's really worth the effort.

Comment: I am assuming that mass updating all the packages from Melpa/GNU Elpa does not apply to your use case?

Comment: I have a single `.emacs` which I share among many environments. They all already have an old version of `s` installed. When I load Emacs next in each of these environments I will get errors due to missing functions in the old version that I would rather avoid. Yes, I can fix them by doing a mass update from the `package-list-packages` interface one environment at a time. Just like before I had `use-package` I would have installed the packages one environment at a time.

Comment: Don't you want all your environments to be running the *same* config, so that you can have consistent behaviour everywhere? If you put your config under version control, all copies can be identical, without worrying about tracking individual version numbers.

Comment: My `.emacs` is under version control. Are you suggesting putting my `elpa` directory under version control also?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution does not invoke `use-package`, but instead uses the included `package.el` functionality.  Either way it should get the job done:

```el
;; (source: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/22174/93)
(defun package-update (package &optional version)
  "Update a package from the package archives.
If VERSION is nil, update the package to the most recent version
available.  Otherwise, VERSION should be a version string, or a
list of the type returned by `version-to-list'. The package will
be updated only if the currently installed version is less than
the version specified, even if a newer version is available."
  (unless package--initialized
    (package-initialize t))
  (unless package-archive-contents
    (package-refresh-contents))
  (let* ((current (cadr (assoc package package-alist)))
         (current-version (if current (package-desc-version current) '(-1)))
         (pkg-desc (cadr (assoc package package-archive-contents)))
         (pkg-version (and pkg-desc (package-desc-version pkg-desc)))
         (target-version (or (and (stringp version) (version-to-list version))
                             version
                             pkg-version)))
    (when (version-list-< current-version target-version)
      (if (null pkg-desc)
        (error "Package `%s' not found in package archives" package))
      (if (version-list-< pkg-version target-version)
        (error "A suitable version of `%s' is not available" package))
      (package-install pkg-desc)
      (if current
          (package-delete current)))
    nil))
```

With that function defined, you could add the following to your init

```el
(package-update 's '(1 10 0))
```

to ensure that your currently-installed version of the `s` package is at least version 1.10.0